# Синхронизация потоков при наращивании count += 1 глобальной переменной

Tags: python, многопоточность

Версия Python 3.5, использую модуль threading. Нужна ли синхронизация, когда потоки изменяют общую глобальную переменную в один момент времени? В книгах пишут, что нужно использовать Lock(), но и без него не возникает не каких проблем. Пример кода из книги:

```
import threading, time


count = 0


def adder():
    global count
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    count += 1

threads = []
for i in range(100):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=adder, args=())
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)


for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(count)
```

Вот здесь, судя по книге, должно каждый раз выдавать разные числа, так как одновременно 100 потоков в один момент времени меняют переменную count. Но почему-то всё нормально срабатывает. Это в какой-то версии было исправлено или как? Объясните, кто знает.

Comment: Не полагайтесь на незадокументированные детали реализации используемого python. Добавьте явный Lock(), если логика примера это требует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Атомарные`](http://www.michurin.net/tools/python-threads.html) операции.

Переключение нитей происходит только между отдельными байт-код операциями. Сами же операции неделимы. Посмотреть, как выглядит байт-код можно с помощью модуля [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html)

[Вот](http://www.quizful.net/post/thread-synchronization-in-python) некоторые потокобезопасные операции:

- чтение или изменение одного атрибута объекта
- чтение или изменение одной глобальной переменной
- выборка элемента из списка
- модификация списка "на месте" (т.е. с помощью метода append)
- выборка элемента из словаря
- модификация словаря "на месте" (т.е. добавление элемента, или вызов
  метода clear)

Comment: [`count+=1` реализован несколькими инструкциями](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1717514/4279)

Answer (score 5):

> нужна ли синхронизация когда потоки изменяют общую глобальную переменную в один момент времени?

[Нужна](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1718843/4279). Вот ещё пример (запускаем 100 потоков, увеличиваем глобальную переменную `niters` раз):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Pool

niters = 100000
count = 0


def increment():
    global count
    count += 1


with Pool(100) as pool:
    for _ in range(niters):
        pool.submit(increment)

assert count == niters, count
```

Этот код может приводить к `AssertionError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "./__main__.py", line 17, in <module>
    assert count == niters, count
AssertionError: 99981
```

Код легко сделать threadsafe, добавлением lock:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Pool

niters = 100000
count = 0


def increment(lock=threading.Lock()):
    global count
    with lock:
        count += 1


with Pool(100) as pool:
    for _ in range(niters):
        pool.submit(increment)

assert count == niters, count
```

Только одна `+=` операция выполняется в любое время (что делает потоки бессмысленными в этом примере. См. видео [Thinking about Concurrency, Raymond Hettinger, Python core developer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv25Dwe84g0)), поэтому гарантируется, что `count == niters` в конце.