# Блокировка в процессах, не потоках

Tags: python, блокировки

Есть небольшой код, в котором в разных процессах увеличивается на единицу переменная из порождающего процесса:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe, Lock

counter = 0


def foo(pipe, c):
    c += 1
    pipe.send(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    childEnd, parentEnd = Pipe()

    for n in range(3):
        Process(target=foo, args=(childEnd, counter)).start()
        with Lock():
            counter = parentEnd.recv()

    print('counter = %s' % counter)
```

Вопрос: нужен ли Lock перед изменением переменной? Так как инкрементирование происходит с помощью канала Pipe, не пойму нужно ли предохраняться перед изменением общей переменной?

Comment: Нет, блокировки не нужны.

Comment: недавно обсуждали, оказывается нужны

Comment: @jfs, не найду тот вопрос о атомных операциях.
упд. нашел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702135/Синхронизация-потоков-при-наращивании-count-1-глобальной-переменной

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Синхронизация потоков при наращивании count += 1 глобальной переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702135/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-count-1-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: @eri То вопрос был про потоки, а это про процессы и передачу через каналы которые с потоками не чего общего не имеют, так что не дубликат

Comment: Лок нужен по тем же причинам.

Comment: а эта переменная у тебя там вообще изменяется? вроде автоматом в общую память она не должна попасть... я всегда через менеджер такие штуки делал

Comment: @eri Да изменяется, но через канал, а не в рамках одного процесса в отличии от потоков

Comment: @eri у каждого процесса своя память со своими переменными.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev поэтому и удивляюсь что у автора работает

Comment: @eri какие локи при работе с пайпой? Тут нет никакого контеншена, с одной стороны пишется, с другой читается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже в случае потоков конфликтов бы не было, т.к. дочерние потоки к переменной `counter` не обращаются, поэтому `Lock` не был бы нужен.

В данном случае `Lock` тоже не нужен, т.к. память процессов изолирована, и переменные `counter` для каждого из процессов разные. Чтобы это увидеть, можно добавить вывод значения этой переменной в главном и дочерних процессах: несмотря на то что в главном процессе переменная будет меняется, в дочерних процессах она остается равна 0

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

counter = 0


def foo(pipe, c):
    c += 1
    pipe.send(c)
    print('child:', counter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    childEnd, parentEnd = Pipe()

    for n in range(3):
        Process(target=foo, args=(childEnd, counter)).start()
        counter = parentEnd.recv()
        print('main:', counter)

    print('counter = %s' % counter)
```

Вывод:

```
child: 0
main: 1
child: 0
main: 2
child: 0
main: 3
counter = 3
```

Comment: @jfs, переформулировал, Lock убрал