# Потокобезопасная реализация одиночки

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton, шаблон-одиночка

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста относительно моей реализации одиночки. Реализую как рекомендуют [pep-0318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples):
Итого, получается код, вида:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instance = {}

    def get_instance():
        if cls not in instance:
            instance[cls] = cls()
        return instance[cls]
    return get_instance()

@singleton
class MyClass:
      ******
```

Я никак не могу понять, почему работает мой код. Я экспериментировал с 10 потоками, которые вызывают один и тот же метод этого класса, метод отрабатывает по времени долго (4-5 сек. реального времени), но блокировок вызвать не получилось. Данная реализация является потокобезопасной? Если да, то почему?

Comment: В чистом Python из-за GIL потокам очень сложно сломать друг другу данные.

Comment: Насчет блокировок спорно, опять же из-за GIL, в Python одновременно может исполнятся только 1 поток на процесс. (Предполагаю что используется стандартный CPython в других реализациях (JPython, IronPython) это может отличаться)

Comment: Все верно, используется стандартный CPython. Я тоже думал, что это меня страхует GIL, но тогда я не понимаю, почему методы класса, которые я вызываю отрабатывают одновременно и дают правильные результаты. Если какой-то поток, начинает работать с данным одиночкой, то он должен его заблокировать до тех пор пока не закончит с ним и эту функцию берет на себя GIL? Я правильно понимаю принцип работы? Но тогда почему методы отрабатывают практически одновременно, если метод работает 4-5 сек. реального времени?

Comment: Почему код работает? Он должен падать из-за блокировок. Либо должен работать медленно - второй поток не может использовать одиночку, пока первый его не отпустит

Comment: @Arnial GIL не освобождает вас от конфликтов, связанных с использованием нескольких потоков. Пример: [Синхронизация потоков при наращивании count += 1 глобальной переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702135/23044)

Comment: @S.Kashin словами опишите, что код по вашему должен делать — не как он у вас написан, а какое намерение у кода, какой контекст у задачи? (к чему вы вообще тут шаблон-одиночку пытаетесь использовать). Обратите внимание, что f и f() это очень разные вещи в Питоне.

Comment: Вопрос звучит как "Почему работает, и не падает?" Задача стоит чтобы падало и глючило? По моему проще паренной репы. Достаточно добавить всего 1 букву где нибудь.

Comment: @jsf Я пытаюсь разобраться в работе интерпретатора и многопоточности в частности. MyClass содержит метод start_operation(self, array), который выполняет большое количество операций (например перебор массива array), разные потоки одновременно вызывают этот метод данного одиночки. Я не понимаю, почему они отрабатывают практически одновременно и при это не падают из-за блокировок

Comment: А где должны быть блокировки? Может почитать, как они работают в питоне? Например это: http://asvetlov.blogspot.ru/2011/07/gil.html

Comment: @jsf Спасибо, теперь я понял почему отрабатывает нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CPython (стандартный интерпретатор Python) используется [GIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). 
Из-за него потоки в Python работают не параллельно (за исключением потоков ввода вывода), а по очереди (кооперативно).

Когда один поток запускается GIL блокирует все остальные.

Более подробно о GIL [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), [habr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/84629/)

**Дополнение:**

Сама реализация сингл тона (без доп. блокировок в методах) не является потоко-безопасной 
Прим:

```
@singleton
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def sum(self, arr):
        for val in arr:
            self.a += val

def mrange( limit ):
    for i in range( limit ):
        yield i
        if i % 100 == 0:
            time.sleep(0.000001)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj = MyClass(0)

    start = time.time()

    threads_num = 2
    range_lenth = 100000

    threads = []

    for i in range( threads_num ):
        data =  range( range_lenth )
        #data = mrange( range_lenth )
        t = threading.Thread(target=obj.sum, args=(data,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for thr in threads:
        thr.join()

    print(obj.a)
    print('Программа отработала за:',time.time() - start)
```

При использовании стандартного range программа может выдавать разный результат, т.к. прерывание иногда может происходить внутри операции `+=`

```
% python threads.py 
9999900000
Программа отработала за: 0.024893522262573242
% python threads.py 
8426007253
Программа отработала за: 0.02556920051574707
% python threads.py 
6761264079
Программа отработала за: 0.02519679069519043
```

Но если по какой-либо причине, внутри метода синглтона, будет происходить прерывание чаще чем требует GIL то результат будет стабилен и верен. (Если раскомментировать `data = mrange`).

```
% python threads.py 
9999900000
Программа отработала за: 0.10795187950134277
% python threads.py 
9999900000
Программа отработала за: 0.08879899978637695
% python threads.py 
9999900000
Программа отработала за: 0.10483145713806152
```

Comment: Да, GIL. Но в третьей версии Python GIL отрабатывает максимум 200 тиков либо 5 мс. Затем поток отпускает GIL. Если метод обрабатывающий запрос работает несколько секунд, и этот метод принадлежит одиночке (соответвенно метод-обработчик тоже один), то как его используют несколько потоков и приходят на финиш с примерно одинаковым результатом?

Comment: @S.Kashin сколько тиков в методе самого одиночки?

Comment: Непосредственно в реализации класса? Явно больше 200 :-) Там есть цикл, который работает с итератором, который выдает больше 1000 значений. Соответственно, это уже как минимум 1000 тиков. Работает он 5 секунду, что несколько больше 5 миллисекунд

Comment: @S.Kashin в установке его в переменную

Comment: Ну если я правильно понимаю механизм, то 2. Первый резервирование адреса под переменную, второй создание ссылки, в результате получаем такую констркуцию: переменная-> сслыка-> объект

Comment: Единственно, тут еще плюсом декоратор накладывается

Comment: @S.Kashin ну и какую разницу имеет остальное содержимое метода, какова вероятность того, что критическая секция будет разбита ровно между проверкой и установкой, и даст ли это разбиение хоть какое-то видимое изменение в работе программы? :)

Comment: @Arnial Спасибо, наконец-то до меня дошло. Массивы обрабатываются разные, сответвенно одинока работает по очереди с каждым из них

Comment: @Arnial Спасибо, очень интересны эксперимент

Comment: @S.Kashin: Какое отношение этот ответ имеет к вашему вопросу? Например, к чему GIL здесь упоминать?  1- GIL не обеспечивает потокобезопасность на уровне чистого Питон-кода. (как пример в ответе и демонстрирует)  2- singleton в примере вызывается только в основном потоке (один объект создаётся) Поэтому никакого отношения к "потокобезопасной реализации одиночки" это не имеет. Пример, который мог бы иметь отношение, должен был бы создавать объекты вашего класса в разных потоках (в случае успеха всегда только один объект будет, иначе несколько может создаться)

Comment: @jfs В двух потоках используется общий (разеляемый, глобальный) объект синглтона. 
1) Из-за исползования разделяемых ресурсов в разных потоках, получаются разные результаты, на одних и тех же данных (происходит состояние гонки), несмотря на наличие GIL. 2 - если каждый поток использует свой собственный синглтон, то о потоко-безопасности можно не волноваться т.к. не будет разделяемых данных, тест будет бессмысленным. Реализация может быть потоко безопасной и использовать 1 объект на 2 потока, но это будет требовать явных локов в опасных секциях.

Comment: к чему вы это сказали? 1- это не объясняет к чему ответ приплёл GIL здесь 2- это не объясняет какое отношение пример в ответе имеет к "потокобезопасной реализации одиночки" (никакого)

Comment: Из-за GIL второй пример с (mrange) всегда выдаёт правильный результат, если бы его не было то при большом числе потоков также наблюдалась бы гонка. В вопросе ОП спрашивал является ли сингл тоне потокобезопасным (вариант с range показывает что нет, не является). В первом комментарии к ответу ОП говорил что потоки завершаются с одинаковыми результатами, второй вариант (mrage) показывает что потоко не безопасный метод может стабильно работать при некоторых в внешних к нему условий (в данном случае периодические прерывания внутри генератора).

Comment: 1- вы понимаете, что код, который относится к singleton выполняется у вас *исключительно* в главном потоке? Что метод `sum()` ведёт себя абсолютно также как и в любом другом объекте (вы вообще [можете простую функцию передать с похожими результами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702135/23044) -- никакого отношения к шаблону singleton не имеет!) 2- какое бы взаимотношение между GIL и mrange() не было (не ясно с чего вы взяли, что именно из-за GIL второй пример у вас [иногда, на некоторых системах, версиях Питона] может [случайно] сработать) это не делает код потокобезопасным.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вопрос понял

```
import threading, time


def singleton(cls):

    instance = None

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal instance
        if instance is None:
            instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance
    return inner


@singleton
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        self.a += 1
        self.b += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj = MyClass(1, 2)
    obj1 = MyClass(3, 4)
    print(obj == obj1)

    start = time.time()

    threads = []
    for i in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=obj.add)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for thr in threads:
        thr.join()

    print(obj.a, obj.b)
    print('Программа отработала за:',time.time() - start)
    # 0.002 сек.
```

Comment: Ну почти... У меня не проблема в реализации. Я не понимаю, почему код отрабатывает. Он должен падать