# Почему GIL защищает b.append(i), но не защищает a = a+1

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, интерпретатор

Не до конца понятно, почему разное поведение при выполнении, казалось бы аналогичных действий.

```
    import threading

    a = 0
    b = []

    def f():
        global a, b, c, d
        for i in range(0, 100000):
            a = a + 1
            b.append(i)

    threads = []
    output = []

    for x in range(0,2):
        t = threading.Thread(target=f)
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    for z in threads:
        z.join()

    print(a)
    print(len(b))
```

При этом на выходе значение а всегда < 200 000, а длина списка b всегда = 200 000.
Вопрос - чем провинились int и почему gil не защищает от таких ситуаций?

(Дополнение)
Версия Python 3.6
Нужен ответ именно на поставленный вопрос, а не то, как защититься от такой ситуации )

Comment: Какая версия Python? начиная c 3.4 (может даже ранее, точно не помню) таких проблем нет. Решается очень просто с помощью `threading.Lock()`.

Comment: Версия python 3.6. Вопрос не в том, как это разрешить - вопрос в том, почему происходит именно так.

Comment: Причина в том, что операция инкрементирования на самом деле выполняется в три шага: интерпретатор получает текущее значение счетчика, вычисляет новое значение, и наконец, записывает его в переменную. Если другой поток получает управление в тот момент, когда текущий поток получил значение переменной, он может выполнить вышеописанные 3 шага до того, как их выполнит текущий поток. А так как оба потока получили одно и то же начальное значение переменной, то переменная будет увеличена лишь на 1.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Синхронизация потоков при наращивании count += 1 глобальной переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702135/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что присваивание `a = a + 1` - это не одна операция, а три:

1. чтение `a`;
2. увеличение прочитанного значения на единицу;
3. запись `a`.

*На самом деле их даже больше - надо же еще слот `__add__` у числа проверить.*

Первая и третья операции защищаются при помощи GIL - но вся строчка целиком оказывается не защищена.

Вывод: GIL не защищает программу от гонок. Единственное назначение GIL - это защита интерпретатора Питона.